# On Khelif's example of a group of countable cofinality having the Bergman property

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

A group $G$ is defined to have the *Bergman property* if for any subset $X=X^{-1}$ generating $G$ there exists $n$ such that $X^n=G$.

By a result of [Bergman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X06000276),  the permutation group of any set has the Bergman property. Later this result was extended to some other automorphism groups (of sufficiently homogeneous structures).

Very often the Bergman property
 appears in combination with uncountable cofinality.

A group $G$ is defined to be *of uncountable cofinality* if it can not be written as the countable union of a strictly increasing sequence of proper subgroups.

An example of a group of uncountable cofinality without the Bergman property is any infinite finitely-generated group (for example, $\mathbb Z$).

> **Problem.** Is there a group of countable cofinality possessing the Bergman property?

I came to this question studying macro-uniform functions on finitary balleans of groups, but quickly have found that it was asked by Bergman himself in 2004 or earlier.

In 2006 Anatole Khelif announced a counterexample to this problem and in [his paper in C.R. Acad. Paris](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X06000276) promised: *Les démonstrations des résultats ci-dessus seront publiées ultérieurement*.

But I cannot google any papers of Khelif containing the promised proof. What does it mean? Is there a counterexample or not? Does anybody know the real situation?

Comment: Do you mean a _countable_ union of strictly increasing etc. in the definition of uncountable cofinality?

Comment: @Apollo Yes I had in mind countable. But "sequence" means countable (usually).

Comment: It seems that this paper of Khelif https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X06000276 contains the required example. So, I think it is better to remove this question from MO.

Comment: Note that this property is very inconvenient to deal with and another stronger property (combination with uncountable cofinality), much more practical (passes to quotients, finite direct products, finite index subgroups, extensions...) is usually referred as Bergman property in the literature. I'm not aware of any use of this property, and the only specific result about it is this highly technical proof of Khelif; I'm not sure it has been seriously read at all: the CRAS announcement you mention contains no proof, and the promised paper has never appeared.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your quick answer. Indeed, the stronger Bergman property is an invariant of the coarse structure  and I was curious if its components (the Bergman property and the countable cofinality) also are coarse invariants. The Khelif example (if exists) says that the Bergman property  is not a coarse invariant. What about the countable cofinality?

Comment: I don't know how you see that the (stronger) Bergman property, alias strong boundedness, is a coarse invariant. Uncountable cofinality is a weaker variant, since strongly bounded (resp. uncountable cofinality), means that every length (resp.  every ultrametric length) is bounded.

Comment: @YCor This is our recent (still unpublished) observation with Protasov: a group has the strong Bergman property if and only if each macro-uniform real-valued function on the group is bounded. "Macro-uniform" it is the same as "bornologous", "coarse" and many other names for the same property, dual to the uniform continuity. It is clear that the boundedness of macro-uniform functions is a coarse invariant (and very natural coarse invariant).

Comment: The fact I'm familiar with is the (obvious) restatement of being strongly bounded: it means that for every function $L:G\to\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that there are real functions $f:\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$, $f':\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}$, with $f$ increasing and $g(x,-),g(-,x)$ increasing for fixed $x$, such that $L(gh)\le f(L(g),L(h))$ and $L(g^{-1})\le  f'(L(g))$ for all $g,h\in G$, we have $L$ bounded. If we write the same without the requirement on $f'$, we characterize strongly boundedness of semigroups.